# What is the name of this wire-piercing probe?

Tags: connector, wiring, can, probe

I'm looking to get can bus data without cutting the wires. I would like to know the name of the probe pictured below and where to find it.

[image: Photo of wire probes]

Comment: Insulation piercing probes

Comment: Note, if you do this to a vehicle harness, it greatly increases the chances of wire corrosion.

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't be doing this on an automotive/industrial or outdoors application.

Comment: @Lundin what is the best way then to sense can bus signals ?

Comment: Place a probe against an exposed metal area? This has nothing to do with CAN as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probe is the [Fluke TP81](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/accessories/test-leads/tp81) / [TP82](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/accessories/test-leads/tp82). There are other variations by other manufacturers of course.

[image: Fluke TP81 photo]
(Image from [fluke.com](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/accessories/test-leads/tp81))

This style of probe pierces the cable with a small "needle" that is advanced by twisting the colored-ring at the other end. So keep in mind that it does in fact make a (small) hole.

Inside the colored ring is a female banana jack. The TP81 version has 4mm jacks, the TP82 has 2mm jacks.

Answer (score 0):

The probe you are showing is this non-intrusive type I believe: -

[image]

One that is similar: -

[image]

Can be found [here](https://www.hioki.com/en/products/detail/?product_key=6509).

Comment: The first image (photo) of the probe on a wire is the type that actually pierces the cable. The second image is a non-contact variety that is made for specific use cases.